# Dividing an image into tiles in android

Tags: android, image

I am creating a jigsaw puzzle game and for that I want to break my images into tiles. say 4x4. I want to assign each tile a unique name which will be stored in an array. what can be the procedure to break the image into the tiles?

Comment: You could use an ImageView for each piece.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you can create a Bitmap on the fly and create a Canvas for drawing onto it:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
```

And then draw what you want (even parts of other bitmaps) onto the canvas. However, this is NOT what you should do in this case (I'm just mentioning it for general information if you come across this in the future).

In this specific case, since you want bitmaps that are pieces of the original one, you can use this method:

```
Bitmap piece = Bitmap.createBitmap(fullImage, x, y, width, height);
```

Where fullImage is the original full-size bitmap, and x,y,width,height specify the rectangular piece of it you want. You would create one such piece object for each puzzle piece.

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html